# Regex expression for ten digit phone numbers with different formats

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex expression for this phone number:
(212) 328-9521, where the "(", ")" and the space between ")" and 3 are optional.
I've tried this:
`r"\d{3}-? ?\d{3}-\d{4}"` and `r"\(*\d{3}\)*-* *\d{3}-\d{4}"`
but both of these options are not working.

Comment: Try: `^(\(\d{3}\)[ ]?)?\d{3}-\d{4}$`

Comment: I don't think it worked for my case

Comment: @tim `[ ]?` ??? Not ` ?` ?

Comment: @Bohemian I find `[ ]` for a literal space is easier to read, especially given SO's formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want for your case?

```
r"(\(\d{3}\) ?|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}"
```

If you suppose these patterns:

```
(212) 328-9521
(212)328-9521
212-328-9521
```

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
(?:(?:\(\d{3}\))|(?:\d{3})) ?\d{3}-\d{4}
```

matches all three:

```
(212) 328-9521
212 328-9521
(212)328-9521
```